# Why using a separate variable breaks Rust's rules?

Tags: rust, binance

I am trying to subscribe to Binance BookTicker streams. Everything was ok til I tried to pass a dynamic list to the subscriber method.

#### Working version:

```rust
use binance_spot_connector_rust::{
    market_stream::book_ticker::BookTickerStream,
    tungstenite::BinanceWebSocketClient,
};

let stream_adr = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws";
let mut conn = BinanceWebSocketClient::connect_with_url(stream_adr)?;

conn.subscribe(vec![
    &BookTickerStream::from_symbol("BTCUSDT").into(),
    &BookTickerStream::from_symbol("BNBBUSD").into(),
]);
```

#### The version I tried:

```rust
let symbol_lst = vec!["BTCUSDT".to_string(), "BNBBUSD".to_string(), "BTCUSDT".to_string()];

let lst = symbol_lst.iter()
    .map(|x| BookTickerStream::from_symbol(&x))
    .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    ;

// try 1
conn.subscribe(lst.into_iter().map(|x| x.into()));
// ^^^^ the trait `From<BookTickerStream>` is not implemented for `&binance_spot_connector_rust::websocket::Stream`

// try 2
conn.subscribe(lst.into_iter().map(|x| &x.into()));
// returns a reference to data owned by the current function
```

The `subscribe` function [accepts an iterator](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-connector-rust/blob/main/src/tungstenite.rs#L81C15-L81C15) of `Stream`, which means the `BookTickerStream` struct should be converted [into](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-connector-rust/blob/main/src/market_stream/book_ticker.rs#L35).

```rust
// the crate's code from its repository
pub fn subscribe<'a>(&mut self, streams: impl IntoIterator<Item = &'a Stream>) -> u64 {
   ...
}
```

*The `crate::websocket::Stream` is private and cannot be created manually, so the conversion is required.*

#### ENV

```
Rust: 1.74 - stable
Crate: binance_spot_connector_rust = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
```

Comment: Try moving the `.into()` from the `subscribe` call to the `map`. (Note: You might need some type annotations)

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues I have tried so many ways but failed. The problem with type annotation is that the target type is not public. Besides the lack of flexibility of the crate, I should overcome Rust's compiler error, which I cannot figure out.

Comment: If possible, try to send a PR to the crate to make the type public, private types should not be used in public interface. Otherwise you can try moving the `.into()` into `.map` and *not* `.collect`, then just pass the iterator to `subscribe` and hopefully rustc wouldn't need any type annotations.